# How to get multiple type search results from elasticsearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

So, I have `myindex` elastic search index with two types `type1` and `type2`. Both the type has two common fields as `name` and `description`as below:

```
{
"name": "",
"description": ""
}
```

I want 5 results from `type1` and 5 results from `result2` if I specify the size as 10 in a single search query?

The below query gives me 10 results from `type1` if the matching results are more from `type1`:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/myindex/_search?pretty&pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
 "size": 10,
 "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "xyz"
    }
 }
}'
```

I can do this in two different queries as below, but I want to do it in one go.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/myindex/type1/_search?pretty&pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
 "size": 5,
 "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "xyz"
    }
 }
}'

curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/myindex/type2/_search?pretty&pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
 "size": 5,
 "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "xyz"
    }
 }
}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [multisearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) and the results will come back in two separate arrays.

```
GET /_msearch --data-binary

{ "index" : "myindex" , "type" : "type1" }
{ "size" : 5, "query" : { "match" : { "name" : "xyz" } } }
{ "index" : "myindex", "type" : "type2" }
{ "size" : 5, "query" : { "match" : { "name" : "xyz" } } }
```